# many objects float and rotate on a large scale ocean

Tags: edit-mode

I made these bowls with many ears around them like a sprocket. The idea is to make an animation with many of these bowls (something like 60) floating in an large scale ocean (200m) and let them rotate like sprockets. [image] [image]
What is the best way to do this? Now I made an ocean with the ocean modifier and add a lot of subdivisions to it. Now animated the rotation of one bowl with keyframes, copied the bowl, and changed the direction of the key frames of the next bowl. In edit mode I changed the rotation of the bowl a little bit so the ears would not collide. I have made a
I would like to let the bowls make some waves, so I added a dynamic plane to shrink-wrap to the ocean so I can copy the rotation (except from the z-axes) and the location to the bowl. I made a cylinder for the inside of the bowl. So I added a Boolean to the ocean and linked it to the cylinder. Otherwise, the water of the ocean would flow into the inside of the bowl. I added Paintbrush to them and added a dynamic paint canvas to the ocean. [image]

This altogether is hard for my computer. Often blender shows not responding by every simple step. I even have not really started with shading the ocean and did not changed things in the ocean modifier. How can I make this easier to handle for my computer? Or are there other better ways to realize my idea?

Comment: It's kinda hard to imagine what exactly you are trying to do, but if the bowls don't move, you could join all of the boolean meshes together instead of having 60 separate modifiers.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but yeah the bowls should move.