# Bowls who must work like gears floating on a large scale ocean with Animation node

Tags: animation-nodes

I made these bowls with many ears around them like a sprocket. The idea is to make an animation with many of these bowls (something like 30) floating in an large scale ocean (200m) and let them rotate like gears. The best thing would be if the waves creates the rotations.

[image]

What is the best way to do this? I think the solution is in animation or geometry nodes with instancing, otherwise i think it's very hard to render for my computer.
I am not that experienced in Animation nodes nor in geometry nodes.

The problems and needs that i am facing:

- How can i instance the bowls with animation nodes  and let them work as gears (rotate the next the other way around).
- boolean for the inside of the bowls so that ocean flows not through the bowl.
- Let the bowls and especially the ears collide with eachother. (Not overlap!)
- I am using for the ocean the ocean modifier. How can i let the bowls float and wiggle a bit on the ocean. I think with the shrinkwrap modifier?! The best way i think is to instance the bowls along a spline and let that spline shrinkwrap on the ocean. Then I can also animate the curve over the y or x-axes. So that it looks more like it's floating.
- Using dynamic paint so that the bowls creates little waves in the ocean.
- The distance between the bowls may vary a little. So that it looks more like it's floating.

Here is the blenderfile of the bowl.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wfpxEpIzACRYvVCHag1JyqbYq26vcFE8/view?usp=sharing
Excuse me for my bad english. I am a forreign speaker.

Comment: Perhaps this could be an edit to your previous question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213461/many-objects-float-and-rotate-on-a-large-scale-ocean